# Hiding the test result overview charts

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager

After running test cases, I do not want to show '**Failed Test by Reason**' and '**Failed Test by analysis**' pie charts until they have a value assigned. As soon as i select a '**failure type**' and '**resolution**' for these two charts should show up. if i don't mark '**failure type**' and '**resolution**' for a failed test case these pie charts should not be displayed. Yet '**Current state of Test**' pie chart should be displayed after each test run.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Also, i need to know what kind of scripts (i.e. js/VB/C# or some other format like batch file) are accepted as setup and cleanup script in automated test setting in test manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding the Pie charts is not possible, we cannot change the UI of MTM it is designed to show the charts. These charts are added to give us an overview of the reason for test failure and analysis of failure.

It's a general practice to use batch file scripts as setup and clean script in Test Manager.